# cant uninstall features from windows server 0x800f0922 error

Tags: windows, active-directory

0x800f0922 error when trying to uninstall active directory Certificate services  on Windows Server 2012.

Is it needs an full privilege permission or its done by any regular admin user?

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot i noticed that i should turn off the **iis** when uninstalling this feature ..

This is written as a note in https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200144.aspx#BKMK_ADCS after finishing uninstalling.